# Simplify this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to simplify this polynomial in a simple way but can't seem to figure out a way. Can someone help me out? The values 30 and 67 is to the power 2011.

$$\frac{30^{2011}\cdot 67^{2011}}{30}$$

**Edit: I have to find the remainder.**

Comment: This is not a polynomial but a numerical expression.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gcd(30,67)=1$, (because $67$ is prime), we can only simplify the factors of $30$. The result is
$$
30^{2010}\cdot 67^{2011}=67(30\cdot 67)^{2010}
$$
the remainder is $0$, because $30$ divides the numerator.

Comment: Is there be something missing? The answers given(MCQ) were either 
1)0 2)1 3)3 4)5 5)11. I'm having trouble imagining how to get to such an answer as even with simple simplification it is a massive value.

Comment: What is the entire question?

Comment: @Tharindu are you sure you copied the question exactly as asked in your book?

Comment: @Ragnar No, seriously. I wrote that answer but then I saw the bar "1 new answer."

Comment: @Ragnar Thats the thing. A friend handed me over the question and he can't seem to find the original question. I think we've missed a point here and its asking for something different than plain division.

Comment: @Ragnar my mistake it is to find the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{30^{2011}}{30^1} = 30^{2010}$

Edit: The remainder is 0, since 30 divides the numerator as shown above

Edit: Fixed typo

Comment: Pls explain where does the '1001' come from.

Comment: @Mick Sorry, read it wrong

Comment: That's alright because errors/typos are not uncommon. However, the edited result should be under the "EDIT" so that other readers will not be confused by the comment/answer.